# Caching in Gatsby JS

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, strapi

I have this Gatsby app where when I visit home page everything loads at first including the Testimonials section. However, when I visit another page, for instance the Blog list page and then click on the link back to homepage the data on Testimonials component won't load and you will see a blank area of the app where the Testimonials section is placed. In order to see the Testimonials list, you will have the refresh the page again.

For the record the data on my Testimonials component are being pulled out on Strapi JS that is deployed on Heroku.

So far I got this on my `index.js`:

```
import React from "react"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"
import Layout from "../components/Layout"
import Header from "../components/Header"
import Testimonials from '../components/Testimonials'
import Blogs from '../components/Blogs'
import SEO from '../components/SEO'

export default function Home({ data }) {
  
  const { 
    allStrapiBlogs: { nodes:blogs },
  } = data

  return (
     <>
    <SEO />
    <div className="main-container">
      <Layout>
      <Header />
      <Testimonials title="Testimonials" />
      <Blogs title="Latest Blogs" blogs={blogs} showAllBlogLinks/>
      <Map />
      </Layout>
    </div> 
    </>
  )
}

export const query = graphql`
  {
    allStrapiBlogs(filter: {featured: {eq: true}}, sort: {fields: published_date, order: DESC}, limit: 6) {
      nodes {
        id
        title
        content
        slug
        published_date(formatString: "MMMM DD, YYYY")
        featured_image {
          childImageSharp {
            fluid {
              ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

  }
`
```

And then on my `Testimonials.js` component:

```
import React from "react"
import { graphql, useStaticQuery } from "gatsby"
import Image from "gatsby-image"
import { FaStar } from "react-icons/fa"
import Title from './Title'

const query = graphql`
  {
    allStrapiTestimonials {
      nodes {
        id
        name
        cite
        text
        photo {
          childImageSharp {
            fluid{
              ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid_withWebp
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`

const Testimonials = ({ title }) => {

  const data = useStaticQuery(query)
  const { allStrapiTestimonials: { nodes:testimonials } } = data

  return (
    <div className="testimonial-section section-padding" id="testimonial" data-aos="zoom-in">
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-lg-12">
            <div className="section-title-two center">
                <Title title={title} />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
  
        <div className="testimonial-wrap row">
          <div className="testimonial-slider owl-carousel">

              { testimonials.map(item => {
                    const { id, name, cite, text, photo } = item

                    return(
                      <div className="col-xl-8 col-lg-10 col-12 ml-auto mr-auto" key={id}>
                      <div className="testimonial-item mt-40">
                        <div className="testimonial_img">
                             <Image fluid={photo.childImageSharp.fluid} alt={name} style={{ position: "absolute", overflow: "visible", display: "block", width: "211px",  height: "207px" }}  />
                          </div>
                        <div className="testimonial_content xs-mt-40">
                          <div className="testimonial_content_item mb-30">
                            <div className="testimonial_content__pro">
                              <h4 className="mb-10">{ name }</h4>
                              <p>{ cite }</p>
                            </div>
                            <ul className="d-none d-sm-inline-block">
                              <li><FaStar></FaStar></li>
                              <li><FaStar></FaStar></li>
                              <li><FaStar></FaStar></li>
                              <li><FaStar></FaStar></li>
                              <li><FaStar></FaStar></li>
                            </ul>
                          </div>
                          <div>
                            <p>{ text } </p>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    )
                })}

          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
  )
}

export default Testimonials
```

Any idea what's causing this error? How can I fix it?

Comment: It's kinda tough to say at first glance.  But what is that <Preloader /> component? I don't see that being imported anywhere. Do you have the Gatsby site hosted anywhere?

Comment: I removed the Preloader for now since its not the cause of the issue. It works the same way as it is without it. Nope I don't have

Comment: Have you tried navigating back to the home page with the JS console open to see if it logs any errors?

Comment: Did not find any error...

Comment: Is your static query been triggered once you return to the home page? Can you debug it?  I think your issue relies on your jQuery addition, which blocks React's rehydration

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gatsby JS: Preloader is loading forever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65802810/gatsby-js-preloader-is-loading-forever) The issue relies on your approach, both questions are the same since they share the root implementation

Comment: @ Ferran Buireu I am not sure but what I know is that when I visit the homepage I will need to refresh the page in order for these to load again. Thus the rehydration doesnt happen. The Testimonials has its own component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've faced a similar issue a few months ago and the fix depends strictly on the implementation and your code. Basically, what is happening is that React's doesn't understand that he needs to rehydrate some components because pointing to some global objects as `window` or `document` of the DOM, outside the React's ecosystem (without using states) may block that rehydration, in your cause, because of jQuery.

All the possible solutions that bypass this issue will be patches (like trying to add the cache). The ideal solution would avoid using jQuery, which points directly to the DOM, with React, which manipulates the virtual DOM (vDOM).

There's nothing wrong with the code you've shared, however, based on some other questions that you did, you are using jQuery and using the window object, which prevents the rehydration of some React components. You should get rid of jQuery or using some React-based approach. Something like this should do the trick to force a loader across the whole site:

```
const Layout = ({ children }) => {
       const [loader, setLoader]=useState(true);
    
       useEffect(()=>{
        setTimeout(()=> {
           setLoader(false)
        }, 400)
       }, [])

  return  <section className={`site__wrapper`}>
    <Header />
    <main>{loader ? <Preloader/> :  children}</main>
  </section>;
};
```