# Gatsby JS: Preloader is loading forever

Tags: jquery, reactjs, gatsby, strapi

I copied a simple full page preloader via jQuery on my Gatsby app. The preloader works however instead of disappearing after 4 seconds its loading forever on production but on local it works just fine.

Here's my `Preloader` component:

```
import React from 'react'

 const Preloader = () => {
    return (
        <div id="loader-wrapper">
        <div id="loader"></div>
        <div className="loader-section section-left"></div>
        <div className="loader-section section-right"></div>
    </div>
    )
}

export default Preloader
```

And then on my `script.js` (which was included inside `<Helmet>`):

```
jQuery.noConflict();
    
(function ($) {

    var windows = $(window);

    /* preloader */
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('body').addClass('loaded');
        $('h1').css('color','#222222');
    }, 400);
    
   
})(jQuery);
```

I added this preloader on my `index.js`:

```
return (
     <>
    <Preloader />
    <SEO />
    <div className="main-container">
      <Layout>
      <Header />
      <Testimonials title="Testimonials" />
      <Blogs title="Latest Blogs" blogs={blogs} showAllBlogLinks/>
      <Map />
      </Layout>
    </div> 
    </>
  )
}
```

Any idea what's causing this and how to fix it?

Comment: Your issue relies on the usage of `window` outside React's ecosystem. You are blocking the rehydration of your components, that why I said that you shouldn't mix approaches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've faced a similar issue a few months ago and the fix depends strictly on the implementation and your code. Basically, what is happening is that React's doesn't understand that he needs to rehydrate some components because pointing to some global objects as `window` or `document` of the DOM, outside the React's ecosystem (without using states) may block that rehydration, in your cause, because of jQuery.

All the possible solutions that bypass this issue will be patches (like trying to add the cache). The ideal solution would avoid using jQuery, which points directly to the DOM, with React, which manipulates the virtual DOM (vDOM). This line is breaking your rehydration:

```
var windows = $(window);
```

> The most weird thing here is that on local upon running npx gatsby
> develop it shows all of my data. Really weird

It's not, again: `gatsby develop` occurs in the browser, where there's a `window` object, on the other hand, `gatsby build` occurs in the server (Node) where there's no [`window` or other global objects](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/debugging-html-builds/) because they are not even created.

In addition, you can easily transform this snippet:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    document.querySelector("body").classList.add("loaded");
    document.querySelector("h1").style = "color: #222222";
}, 400)
```

Into a React-based one, using hooks:

```
   const [loader, setLoader]=useState(true);

   useEffect(()=>{
    setTimeout(()=> {
       setLoader(false)
    }, 400)
   }, [])

return (
     <>
     <SEO />
    {loader 
      ? <Preloader />
      : <div className="main-container">
         <Layout>
            <Header />
            <Testimonials title="Testimonials" />
            <Blogs title="Latest Blogs" blogs={blogs} showAllBlogLinks/>
            <Map />
         </Layout>
       </div> 
     }
    </>
  )
}
```

As a resume. You are setting initially the loader as true (`useState(true)`), and once the DOM tree is loaded (`useEffect` with empty `deps`, `[]`), you trigger your `setTimeout` function, which toggles the value of `loader` from `true` to `false`. This will choose what component render using a ternary condition at: `loader ? <Preloader/> : <OtherComponents />`

If you need to use the `window` size object, you can use a React-based approach, like the one provided [here](https://usehooks.com/useWindowSize/).

> Is there a way to improve this and make the preloader loads everytime
> you visit another page?

Yes, the idea is to move that loader logic to the `<Layout>` component, since all the pages will share it:

```
const Layout = ({ children }) => {
       const [loader, setLoader]=useState(true);
    
       useEffect(()=>{
        setTimeout(()=> {
           setLoader(false)
        }, 400)
       }, [])

  return  <section className={`site__wrapper`}>
    <Header />
    <main>{loader ? <Preloader/> :  children}</main>
  </section>;
};
```

I don't know how your `<Layout>` component looks like but the idea is to add something similar. Since your `<Layout>` is shared across your site, each re-rendering of the component will rehydrate this component, forcing the initial loader state as `true` and changing it to `false` at 400ms, rendering the `children`, which is everything wrapped inside the `<Layout>` component on other pages.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Would this preloader react version loads everytime that the path changes? For example, I am on blog page then I click on homepage link. As much as possible I want my preloader to load everytime I visit another page by clicking links. Right now the `gatsby-browser` answer only loads whenever you refresh the page but when you click and go to separate page it wont load it. Is there a way to improve this and make the preloader loads everytime you visit another page?

Comment: It will appear every time since, at the component rendering, it's set to `true` initially, once 400ms it will change to false and it will display the other content. I will update the answer by providing another workaround

Comment: Yeah. That would be great if the preloader always loads first whenever you change routes or click on a different page not needing to do a hard refresh to see the preloader first.

Comment: I've updated the answer. Ideally, it's not a good practice for the user to be forced to see a loader if you don't need to perform any asynchronous action (like data fetching) you are just forcing the user to wait 400ms because you want.

Comment: Thanks for this. I will check it.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried adding your code inside `gatsby-browser.js` instead something like this?

```
export const onInitialClientRender = () => {
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.querySelector("body").classList.add("loaded");
        document.querySelector("h1").style = "color: #222222";
    }, 400)
}
```

Comment: This one works but it actually affects my other sections. For instance, after adding this my testimonials and blogs section did not appear anymore.

Comment: The most weird thing here is that on local upon running `npx gatsby develop` it shows all of my data. Really weird.